# DevExpress BarManager SaveLayoutToStream

Tags: wpf, exception, devexpress

I have a window full of DevExpress controls. The prominent control is a DockLayoutManager containing a TabbedGroup (tabs contain one of: pivot table control or grid control). Surrounding this control are other dockable windows as well as a item menu along the top of the window.

I would like to save the layout of the item menu bar by calling the SaveLayoutToStream on the BarManager object.

This function will complete successfully if and only if the layout of the prominent control is identical to the original layout (i.e. at design-time). If I drag the individuals tabs and dock them within the DockLayoutManager, then I get the following exception:

```
Exception of type 'DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Serialization.DuplicateSerializationIDException' was thrown.

 at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Serialization.DuplicateSerializationIDException.Assert(IDXSerializable dxObj1, IDXSerializable dxObj2)
 at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Serialization.DXSerializer.SerailizationStore.<.ctor>b__4(IDXSerializable dxObj)
 at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Serialization.DXSerializer.AcceptCore(DependencyObject dObj, Action`1 visit, IEnumerable`1 parentIDs)
 at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Serialization.DXSerializer.Accept(DependencyObject dObj, AcceptNestedObjects acceptNested, Action`1 visit)
 at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Serialization.DXSerializer.SerailizationStore..ctor(DependencyObject root, AcceptNestedObjects acceptNested)
 at DevExpress.Xpf.Core.Serialization.DXSerializer.SerializeCore(DependencyObject root, Object path, String appName, DXOptionsLayout options, AcceptNestedObjects acceptNested)
 at DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.BarManager.SaveLayoutToStream(Stream stream)
 at LayoutExtensions.GetLayout(BarManager view) in C:\LayoutHelper.cs:line 136
```

Answer (score 0):

We have reviewed the callstack and cannot even imagine what can cause this issue to appear.  Please post a sample project showing this issue to the [DevExpress support center](http://devexpress.com/support/center).  We will research why the problem appears and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

See

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E2272.aspx
and
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q325319.aspx

If you are using objects of the same type in your layout, assign the DXSerializer.SerializationID property for all objects

For example

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns:core="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
        xmlns:dxdo="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/docking"
```

...

```
<dxdo:DockLayoutManager Name="FilterGridDockLayoutManager" core:DXSerializer.SerializationID="dock1" >
```